# Firebase - Admin.firestore vs functions.firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-admin-sdk

I'm newbie on cloud function. I have some confusions.

1. Is there any difference between admin.firestore and
   functions.firestore?
2. Is admin.database for real-time database?
3. So if cloud functions are basically written as JavaScript or
   TypeScript in Node.js environment, then I can write them with
   JavaScript. But documentation made me confused about that. Because
   whenever I read the documentation, it gives things different. For
   example,

[image: Cloud Firestore triggers-> onWrite]
Above code to get a document, it uses `document('some/doc')`.
[image]
But, above code it uses `doc('doc')` to achieve the same functionality. If all of them come form firestore, why do both differ each other?

Can someone help me to understand these questions? Thank you for all your supports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`functions.firestore`: is used to set up a [trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events). You can set up a listener on a document path so that whenever an event happens on that document (create/update/delete etc.), this function will be executed. See how to create one [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#writing-triggered_functions).

`admin.firestore`: is used to create a reference to a firestore database. You can perform various operations on firestore collection/documents using admin sdk through that reference. See [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore).

Comment: So, I can catch and trigger on firestore with functions.firestore and react them with admin.firestore. Is that right?

Comment: @FerdaNahitFIDANCI Correct! That's one of the many possible use case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It helped a lot.